# Where do I ask Wireless Communications Questions

Tags: discussion

Please consider this as a soft question. I am wondering where is the best place to ask questions related to Digital Communications and Wireless Communications.

Is there any stack exchange that can help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: This is the place.

Comment: Cool thanks Jim...Felt like this place is more of signal processing type of questions @JimClay

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jim; though this particular "soft" question is more a meta question than a straight DSP.SE question. :-)  The other way to do it is to just ask the question on a vaguely-relevant *.SE site, and ask the mods to move it to another site if a more relevant one shows up.